# poptorootview when click on alerrtview ok

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I have a home view ,when click on that it is going to another view again i am going to another view.when click on a button on that view a modalview will appear and then subsequently 3 more modal views when click on each modalview.when click on the final modalview an alert will appear and when click on that alert i want to show the root homeview.Is it possible
?

Answer (score 1):

Display AlertView using given code snippet:

UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message: @"Alert Message"
                                                   delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

Delegate Method implementation :

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code given below:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert Message?" message:@"Error......" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK"] autorelease];
[alert show];
```

The implemention alertView's delegate functions is given below

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //cancel clicked ...do your action
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        //OK clicked
         [self.navigationController popToViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I did like this but it is still staying on the current view itself not going to rootview.

Answer (score 0):

```
int c=[self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-4;
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:c] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

just give the delegate in .h file and after in delegate method of alertview write bellow code..

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];///this line is important..
    }
    else{
      // do your action...
     }
}
```

i hope this answer is useful to you..

:)

Comment: you push every view from homeviewcontroller?? and also first try this code on simple UIButton click event just try...

Comment: put [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; this line in also else part in above method ... or change the condition from buttonindex == 1 to buttonindex == 0.